# Autofill empty arrays with dragging functions from last non-empty row in Col C

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to make an autofill function in  Google Sheets using Apps Script. There is much more data in Col A and Col B so I want to get the last non-empty cell in Column C and then autofill the blank spaces with dragging function from Col C Last non-empty row to the end. By the Col C, I understand Col C with all columns with data to the end (C, D, E, F...) Here is some code.

```
function autofill() {
  var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  for(u=4; u <= LastRow; u++){

  var CheckIfEmpty = ss.getRange(u, 3).getValues(); 
    if (CheckIfEmpty == "") {
      return u;

      Logger.log(u);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: After `return` the logging step `Logger.log(u)` does not make too much sense, I guess.

Comment: Actually with Logger I would like to check If "u" returns me the last non-empty row in C column but it doesn't work like that

Comment: What do you mean by "dragging function"? Could you share an example, please?

Comment: I mean if I have for example function in C2 and want it as well in C3, C4, C5 etc with relative cell i drag this function down. If I do this action on macro scripts return me this kind of code:

spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('E6:E9'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);

Answer (score 2):

**Auto Fill Dialog**

```
function runMe() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var html='<html><head>';
  html+='<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>';
  html+='<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">';
  html+='<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>';
  html+='<style>input{margin:5px 5px 5px 0;}</style>';
  html+='</head><body>';
  html+='<input type="text" id="src" placeholder="Select Source Range" size="50" /><input type="button" value="Get Source Range" onClick="getSrcRange();" />';
  html+='<br /><input type="text" id="des" placeholder="Select Destination Range" size="50" /><input type="button" value="Get Destination Range" onClick="getDesRange();" />';
  html+='<br /><input type="button" value="Execute" onClick="execute();" />';
  html+='<script>';
  html+='function getSrcRange(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(obj){$("#src").val(obj.range);}).getActiveRange();}';
  html+='function getDesRange(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(obj){$("#des").val(obj.range);}).getActiveRange();}';
  html+='function execute(){var src=$("#src").val();var des=$("#des").val();google.script.run.execute({src:src,des:des});}';
  html+='</script>';
  html+='</body></html>';

  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(800);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "AutoFill");
}

function getActiveRange() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  return {range:rg.getA1Notation()};
}

function execute(obj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(obj.src).autoFill(sh.getRange(obj.des),SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
}
```

[image]

I don’t believe there is any dragging trigger but this a way to do it with a dialog. If you’re interested in always doing it with the same ranges that’s a possibility that could done with just a button click.